# Format Brand value in Category view

Tags: categories, customization

I was managed to add "Brand name" to the category view list in the spot between image and category name (or product name). The code I have used is below.

The problem:

1. How can I remove the link from the brand (href part), so it is not clickable? Only product title should be clickable to open product details.
2. How can I apply a style to the Brand value? Ideally I want to use
   same style/color used for the category label in the category view.

The code:

```
function pwb_show_brands_in_loop(){
 global $product;
 $product_id = $product->id;
 $product_brands =  wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'pwb-brand');
 if(!empty($product_brands)){
      echo '<div class="custom-loop-brands">';
      foreach ($product_brands as $brand) {
           echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($brand->term_id).'">'.$brand->name.'</a>';
      }
      echo '</div>';
 }
```

}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'pwb_show_brands_in_loop',1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understood properly, you just have to remove the anchor from your code. Simply use:

`echo $brand->name;`

Instead of:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($brand->term_id).'">'.$brand->name.'</a>';
```

This will just echo the name of your brand. If you want to style it, you can add a class to it as the following:

`echo '<span class="my-brand">'.$brand->name.'</span>';`

And then use the proper style in your `CSS` file to style it. Such as:

```
.my-brand {
    color:#ddd;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - there was an error in my code, so I have just updated it. Not sure if this will change your response. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this and get back with the results. #1 issue is tested - the link is gone. doing styles now :-) You are genius!!!

Comment: It works. Jack, you made my day !!! Let me know if you have an online place and I will write a testimonial. Last tune-up question. How do I add UPPERCASE to this style? .my-brand {
    color:#ddd;
}

Comment: OK - I figured that out for uppercase! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: My website is in my profile, in case you are interested. To uppercase the string, use `text-transform:uppercase` in your style code.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. Im new here. How do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: You can accept/upvote the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer.